# Using fadeOut() and fadeIn() on mouseover and mouseout

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

My problem is that when I am using fadeOut() on mouseover and fadeIn() on mouseout() (on a < li > component), I am not getting the results that I am expecting. What happens is that sometimes when the mouse is not on the object, the buttons that I want to fadeOut() just keep fading in and out in a loop and sometimes the loop stops and sometimes it doesn't.

What is the proper way of using fadeOut and fadeIn with mouseover and mouseout?

here is the code:

```
comment.onmouseout = function() {mouseOut(comment);};
comment.onmouseover = function() {mouseOver(comment);};
```

where comment is a basic < li > with buttons as children

```
function mouseOut(parent){
    var children = parent.childNodes;
    var i=0;
    for(i=1;i<children.length;i++){
        if(children.item(i).tagName=="INPUT"){
            $(children.item(i)).fadeOut();
        }
    }
}
function mouseOver(parent){
    var children = parent.childNodes;
    var i=0;
    for(i=1;i<children.length;i++){
        if(children.item(i).tagName=="INPUT"){
            $(children.item(i)).fadeIn();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your relevant html as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) will solve most of the problems caused by `mouseout`, `mouseover`. `hover` wraps around `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to provide even better handling.

Answer (score 5):

That happens because when the opacity reaches 0 the display is set to none. so the element disappears, trigerring the mouseout.

**quote** from [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

> The .fadeOut() method animates the
>   opacity of the matched elements. **Once
>   the opacity reaches 0, the display
>   style property is set to none**, so the
>   element no longer affects the layout
>   of the page.

So it would be better to [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) the opacity instead

instead of *fadeout*

```
$(children.item(i)).animate({opacity:0},  400);
```

and instead of *fadein*

```
$(children.item(i)).animate({opacity:1},400);
```

---

another issue is that the animations get queued. So you would be better to stop the current animation before starting the next.

instead of *fadeout*

```
$(children.item(i)).stop().animate({opacity:0},  400);
```

and instead of *fadein*

```
$(children.item(i)).stop().animate({opacity:1},400);
```

---

If you could post your HTML it would be easier to post pure jquery code to handle the whole issue.